# Convert a .xls or a .xlsx to a CSV file using Haskell

Tags: excel, haskell

I want to convert a .xls or a .xlxs file to .csv file, I followed the example mentioned on [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xls) module, my build tool is Haskell tool Stack.

This is the code

```
import Data.Xls (decodeXlsIO)

xlsToCSV :: String -> IO ()
xlsToCSV file = do
    worksheets <- decodeXlsIO file
    mapM_ (mapM_ (putStrLn . intercalate ",")) worksheets
```

I was able to import the module but it was throwing the following error-

```
Module ‘Data.Xls’ does not export ‘decodeXlsIO’
  |
2 | import Data.Xls (decodeXlsIO)
```

I want to know where I am missing is and any other resources to convert a .xlxs file to a .csv file.

Comment: which version of `xls` package are you using?

Comment: apparently, `stackage`'s package version is `xls-0.1.2`. The function `decodeXlsIO` has been added in version `0.1.3` as you can check in the github repo. You can add the new version in `extra-deps` section in `stack.yaml`

Comment: Thanks for that, I forgot to check that, I will try it and get back! :)

Comment: It is working now, it was such a silly mistake!